# If loop causing items to spawn after true condition has changed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
    float CloudPoint = rnd.Next (-9, 9);
    double CloudRate = rnd.Next (1, 20);
    Debug.Log(CloudRate);
    Vector2 CloudPos;
    CloudPos.y = CloudPoint;
    CloudPos.x = -21;
    if (CloudRate == 10) {
        CloudRate = 0; 
        //Debug.Log(CloudRate);
        Instantiate (Cloud, CloudPos, Quaternion.identity);
    } 
    else {
    }
```

This code waits till CloudRate == 10 then continual spawns Cloud

I would like it to spawn one cloud then stop intil CloudRate == 10 again

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random() isn't *true* random in the sense that it isn't completely unpredictable.

It is instead a seeded random, which means if you give it the same seed value, it will give you the same series of numbers.  When you create a Random() without a seed (as you have done) C# uses the current time as the seed.  If you do this too quickly within a loop, the seed is the same, so the first value is the same, which is why you're seeing a lot of objects spawn at once.

Don't create the System.Random() within the loop, instead create it before the loop and keep a reference to it, this should resolve the issue.